# pascalprecht.translate does not work on an attribute of an bootstrap-filestyled-file-form-element

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've prepared a plunker here, to see the problem: [Angular Translate Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TlKknCgSJp43lzYGtWxX)

The translation is working in general, the only one exception is an attribute field of an bootstrap-filestyled form-file-element.

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- APP_USER_IMAGE -> WORKS -->
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="image">
              "{{ 'APP_USER_IMAGE' | translate }}"
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- APP_FILE_UPLOAD_TXT -> DOES NOT WORK --> 
          <input type="file" filestyle="" 
              id="image" 
              name="image" 
              ng-model="tempData.image" 
              data-button-text="{{ 'APP_FILE_UPLOAD_TXT' | translate }}" 
              data-class-button="btn btn-default" 
              data-classinput="form-control inline" 
              nv-file-select="" 
              class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get the translated value in the `filestyle` directive:

```
function link(scope, element) {
    var options = element.data();
    $translate('APP_FILE_UPLOAD_TXT').then(function (text) {
      options.buttonText = text;
      element.filestyle(options);
    });
}
```

See **[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/udNtzqzojvZ8kYdoknP9?p=preview)**

Comment: yes, thank you very much. I think this part is decisive point `function filestyle ($translate) {..`. $translate is the correct function parameter, that you have to know.. I've already tried 'translate', but the parameter was missing..

Comment: But each time (by every new file-input) you have to adapt the directive, don't you?

Comment: In the above example, it's hardcoded in the directive as the main point was that you can call `$translate` service from the directive. But indeed, if you need to customize it for some file inputs that's a good id to get the key from a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With 2 Modifications you can use the solution with every file-element, without touching the directive each time:

1) In the view

```
data-button-text="APP_FILE_UPLOAD_TXT"
```

2) In the directive

```
function filestyle($translate) {
    var directive = {
        strict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        var options = element.data();
        // old usage support
        options.classInput = element.data('classinput') || options.classInput;
        $translate(options.buttonText).then(function(text) {
            options.buttonText = "&nbsp;" + text;
            element.filestyle(options);
        });
    }
}
```